# Supersized not going full-screen on iPhone 5 + Safari + Landscape

Tags: css, mobile-safari, supersized

I've implemented the Supersize plugin on this page: http://www.olganaum.com/

I've tested the page on a few devices (Android, iPad2, desktop's Chrome), and everything would seem to be ok.

Yet on iPhone 5, when turn the device on landscape mode, this happens:
http://i58.tinypic.com/20fexkk.jpg

As you might see, **the image is not going full screen**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going through the same I went, then the key is on **turning the device**. It seems that when you turn from landscape to portrait and *vice versa*, the images or their container, for some reason, don't render full size again.

As I couldn't find the underlying reason, I applied this fix:

```
var rotationFix = function () {
        jQuery(window).bind('orientationchange', function(e) {
            document.location.reload(true);
        });
    }
```

Do notice this is just an easy exit, and every time you turn the device the page will refresh. If you want to take the solution a step farther, you may paint the containers to see which one is rendering full screen and which is not (and create a solution without refreshing the page).